# Get server response with WebClient.UploadFileAsync method

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using `WebClient.UploadFileAsync` to upload local files to a web server and I am wondering if it is possible to get the any responses from the server after the upload is complete?

When using `WebClient.UploadFile` it is possible to get a byte array containing any response. But I would like to do the upload asynchronously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Subscribe to the `UploadFileCompleted` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfilecompleted.aspx)

From MSDN:

```
client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler (UploadFileCallback);

....

private static void UploadFileCallback(Object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string reply = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (e.Result);
    Console.WriteLine (reply);
}
```